# --proto_path passed empty directory name

Tags: python, protocol-buffers, proto

I'm trying to compile a proto file with the following command:

```
protoc -I=. --python_out=. ./message.proto --proto_path=.
```

But I'm getting this error:

```
--proto_path passed empty directory name.  (Use "." for current directory.)
```

What to do?

Comment: just write " protoc  myfilename.proto "

Answer (score 10):

You should remove `=` in `-I=.` and also remove `--proto_path=.` flag

Answer (score 0):

The command works for me.

> **NOTE** `-I` == `--proto_path` so using both with the same value is redundant

One 'wrinkle' with `protoc` is that the protobuf files must be encapsulated by a `proto_path`.

So, in your case, the current directory must contain a valid `message.proto` file, both for `./message.proto` to be a valid reference and because your `--proto_path` includes the current directory.

Answer (score 0):

In my case, mixing short and long flags `-I=` and `--python_out=` was the problem.

```
$ protoc -I=. --python_out=. ./message.proto
--proto_path passed empty directory name.  (Use "." for current directory.)
```

solution:

```
$ protoc --proto_path=. --python_out=. ./message.proto
```

In your case, removing `-I=.` will fix the problem.

```
$ protoc --python_out=. ./message.proto --proto_path=.
```