# --proto_path passed empty directory name. (Use "." for current directory.)

Tags: python-3.x, protocol-buffers, proto

I am trying to compile a proto file using the following command

```
protoc -I=. --python_out=. ./check.proto
```

It's throwing "--proto_path passed empty directory name.  (Use "." for current directory.)" error.please help me to fix this issue.

Comment: For consistency, I encourage you to use `--proto_path=.` instead of a combination of short flags (i.e. `-I`) and long (i.e. `--python_out`). I suspect the issue is that you can't use `=` with short-flags, i.e. `-I .` but not `-I=.`. If you use the long-flag instead, you can use `--proto_path=.` without issue. Curiously, with bash, I can use your command as-is (`protoc` 3.19.2 on Linux) without issue.

Comment: protoc --proto_path=. --python_out=. ./check.proto   It works on windows. Thanks a lot.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [--proto\_path passed empty directory name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64048132/proto-path-passed-empty-directory-name)